# SQL Error: ORA-00904: "MEBERSHIPID": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a table whereI'm currently trying to add multiple foreign keys in Oracle 
The table scripts is as follows

```
Create table Member
(
memeberID int Not null Primary Key,
membershipID int Not null,
group_id  int not NULL,
Dutycode int not null,
MemberRole varchar(255),
name varchar(255),
last_joined date,
DOB date,
address varchar(255),
CONSTRAINT fk_DutCode FOREIGN KEY (Dutycode)
REFERENCES RaceManagementDuty(Dutycode),

CONSTRAINT fk_GrMemeber FOREIGN KEY (group_id)
REFERENCES Group_member(group_id),

CONSTRAINT fk_Meberships FOREIGN KEY (mebershipID)
REFERENCES Membership(mebershipID)
)
```

Wandering where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a typo error . Change mebershipID to membershipID

```
CONSTRAINT fk_Meberships FOREIGN KEY (membershipID)
REFERENCES Membership(membershipID)
```

There is no column mebershipID in table and so throws error

Comment: change also in this line ..REFERENCES Membership(mebershipID)